# Access $errors inside Laravel Blade Component

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade

I've got a "error message" component which I can use via

```
@component('error-messages')
    // Some slot stuff which is used for various things.
@endcomponent
```

Then within this I try and access `$errors` - However the bag is empty, You can see below when i `@dump($errors)` outside the component, and then within the component.

[image]

When I use `@include` it works, but with `@component` it's empty

I know I could pass `$errors` into the component, but this would need to happen everywhere - which isn't ideal.

Has anybody got any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Share it in main view by:

```
@php
  @View::share('errors', $errors);
@endphp
```

or in controller

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        View::share('item', $item);
        $view = view('admin.param_type.form')->withErrors($validator->errors());
        View::share('errors', $view->errors);
        return $view;
    }
```